# Setting up: sending and email

Tags: transactions, wallet

I've been using Bitcoin Wallet on windows 7 to receive payments successfully but after making my 1st BTC payment the transaction doesn't appear to be clearing (957 confirmations and counting).

The recipient of the payment has asked for my transaction email confirmation but I don't recall setting an email address or where to check if I ever did this.

Please can someone help?

Answer (score 3):

If the transactions is shown in your Bitcoin-Qt client as having confirmations, then the transaction went through and is confirmed. Most systems consider a transaction as confirmed when it has one confirmation, some require up to 6 confirmations, but when a transaction has 957 confirmations, it is practically irreversible.

If your transaction has that amount of confirmations and the receiver did not get it yet, then he has a problem with its client, not you.

There exists no such thing as e-mail confirmations in Bitcoin. It's possible that some clients offer it as a feature, but it is certainly nothing standard to Bitcoin.

*(I don't know who the recipient is and I don't want to accuse anyone, but it seems like he is trying to have you send the transaction again.)*